# Does a star need to be inside a galaxy?

Tags: planets, stars, galaxies

Must a star belong to a galaxy, or could it be completely isolated?

In case it can be isolated (not belong to a galaxy), could it have a planet orbiting around it?

Comment: There could even be a planet without a star [If there are Earth size bodies drifting in space could we identify them?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1913/109)

Comment: No, @JamesJenkins, it couldn't. But this is nothing to do with the underlying physics or history of the universe. It is simply a matter of definition: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet) says *A planet is an astronomical body orbiting a star or stellar remnant that is [...]*. It has a discussion and links to official definitions. The original use of the word did not even include Halley's Comet. This can only be because its orbit was too long or eccentric as it would have met the other criteria at the time (that covered everything from the sun to Saturn)

Comment: @DavidRobinson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet

Comment: Not sure why you ask this in physics -- astronomy had the [same (main) question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29397/11190) not too long ago, with an intriguing image attached to [this answer.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29399/11190) But it's noteworthy that these events are closely linked to galaxies because you do need more matter than usually present in intergalactic space, and that comes from galaxies.

Comment: @anand_v.singh Your point is so pertinent that I have raised a new question: [What orbit does a planet have to have to be a planet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461900/what-orbit-does-a-planet-have-to-have-to-be-a-planet)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

No, stars do not need to be inside a galaxy.  It is estimated that about 10% of stars do not belong to a galaxy [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9801228)].  While most intergalactic stars formed inside a galaxy and were ejected by gravitational interactions, stars can form outside of galaxies as well [[2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/0004-6361:20066692)].

We assume that such stars could have planets, just like stars in a galaxy, although no specific examples have been detected yet.

[1] ["Detection of intergalactic red-giant-branch stars in the Virgo cluster"](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9801228), Ferguson et al.  Nature 391.6666 (1998): 461.

[2] ["Polychromatic view of intergalactic star formation in NGC 5291"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/0004-6361:20066692),
M. Boquien et al.  A&A, 467 1 (2007) 93-106.

Comment: I like how this shows both other answers are wrong. I would have thought star formation only happened in galaxies.

Comment: Could those planets of extra-galactic origin have metals (i.e. anything else than hydrogen and helium)? I thought all those materials were mostly formed and distributed by supernovae.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann If stars can be born outside of a galaxy then they can explode outside of a galaxy as well.

Comment: Some [further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intergalactic_star)...

Comment: If a galaxy would be a prerequisite of star formation, how would the first stars formed before galaxies existed?

Comment: It's worth noting that the example cited, [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGC_5291](NGC 5291) is a pair of interacting galaxies.  During such events large amounts of galactic gas/dust is drawn out of galaxies and compressed via tidal interaction triggering star formation.  That can be considered intergalactic in that such clouds of gas and stars formed in them can be given sufficient velocity to never rejoin the merging galaxies; but also isn't in the sense that it's something that only happens in the immediate vicinity of galaxies.

Comment: I'm not aware of any star formation occurring in deep intergalactic space without any galaxies in the area to serve as a trigger.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [D100 gas tail](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap190128.html)

Comment: @mg30rg I'm purely speculating, but can imagine a model where the first stars form within a mix of spinning, roughly galaxy-equivalent mass, similar to how planets are hypothesized to form within a protoplanetary disk. Which can be sort of thought of as "in galaxies" if we'll allow a loose definition of "galaxy" that doesn't specifically say it contains stars.

Comment: As far as I understand, those stars are mostly ones thrown out of galaxies, and they usually lose planets during that. So most of them(say 90%) do not have planets.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann They must have - stars that don't contain metals are not on the main sequence and are very short-lived; I'm sure we would have noticed the discrepancy, assuming we can distinguish if a star has been ejected or formed outside of a galaxy (I'm not sure we can). They might have different proportions, of course, but so do stars in other galaxies (and even stars within one galaxy). That said, "galaxy" is a bit vague term - I'm not sure if there's some precise definition, but the one I know wouldn't technically exclude galaxies with a hundred stars :)

Answer (score -1):

They probably have to be formed in a galaxy. But they can escape. There are many rogue planets that are found outside of solar systems. NASA has observed many rogue stars as well. This usually happens when galaxies collide and they throw out some of the stars. And yes, the rogue stars can have planets orbiting them

Comment: Looking at the other answer (the one with sources), stars probably don't *have to* be formed in a galaxy.

Comment: @hyde it goes against Kaiser bias, i.e. the likelihood of passing a threshold for gravitational collapse is enhanced if you are sitting on top of a lower density region (e.g. a proto galaxy). So stars probably form in the vicinity of other stars = a galaxy.

Comment: @chris "Any given star was probably formed inside a galaxy" is a much weaker claim than "Stars probably have to be formed inside a galaxy"

Comment: @Taemyr stars like to form together, and in sufficient number this defines what a galaxy is. So yes stars like to form in galaxies. Doesn't mean its impossible for a star to form alone in the middle of nowhere. Its probably just exponentially rare. Having said that I don't think we know the initial power spectrum properties on stellar scales so this is hypothetical.

Comment: @chris: Exponentially rare doesn't jibe with the 10% figure given elsewhere

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would not consider the Virgo cluster to be very empty though :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the source in Thorondor's answer attributes that 10% to stars being stripped off of their host galaxies, not intergalactic star formation.

Comment: @asgallant Mm, fair enough.

Comment: All you need to make a star is sufficient material to aggregate, sufficient time, and a sufficiently dense region of material (or seed). Sure, the process is greatly aided if you have other stars around, providing radiation pressure and collision debris in masse. But you don't need that. You just need a large cloud of hydrogen, a seed, and time for the cloud to coalesce around it.